# MPI send/recv latency jump at 32 MiB message size

Tags: mpi, hpc

For a university project I'm currently working on a slurm supercomputer cluster and have written a number of C programs using MPI.
While profiling one of them I have observed that the time elapsed between an `MPI_Send` and an accompanying `MPI_Recv` operation is a mostly linear function of the message length. However, at around 32 MiB there is a sudden jump in latency from around 10ms to around 20ms. This happens both for two processes on the same node and two processes on separate nodes.

Now I would like to find out why this happens. I'm aware that this is not an MPI intrinsic phenomenon but must be related to the underlying hardware setup, but I'm not sure where to begin looking for an explanation. What are some possible explanations for this and how could I check whether they apply in my case?

Comment: Is there a spike or a jump ?  I mean, does the latency for messages larger than 32MiB go down again, or stay high ?  For anything better than guesses and waffle you will have to tell us what hardware your cluster comprises, especially what kind of interconnect it has.

Comment: It's a jump, you're right, spike is the wrong word. I'm not completely sure which hardware specs are relevant here but I know that the nodes I'm working on are comprised of around two dozen somewhat current Intel Xeon processors and Infiniband (FDR) is used for interconnect.

Comment: You should first measure the latency/bandwidth with a trusted benchmark such as IMB (from Intel) or the OSU benchmark.